# How to get the domain of a request in ASP.MVC if the server uses a load balacer

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 servers: server1 and server2. They are hosted behind a load balncer. That means that when I go to http://myApp.com I will sometimes land on server1 and sometimes on server2.

What is the right way to identify the domain that the user entered in a MVC controller (I want to get "myApp.com" and not "server1").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)`